# setting the height of div based on its sibling and its parent

Tags: html, css

I would like to set a height of a second DIV based on the height of its sibling which comes above it and also the parent container which has both of these DIVs.

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="box-one">
    <label>
      <span class="label-text">Name:</span>
      <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span class="label-text">Description:</span>
      <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="box-two">
    <div class="content">....</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my SCSS code

```
.panel {
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}
.panel label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.panel label .label-text {
  display: block;
}
.panel label input, .panel label textarea {
  width: 90%;
}
.panel .box-one, .panel .box-two {
  display: table-row;
}
.panel .box-two {
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 2px black;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel .box-two .content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Some how I kind of figured a solution with this CSS tables approach, but is there a better approach rather than this? Because this approach needs addtional DIVs to be wrapped around it.

Here is my codepen
http://codepen.io/nirmalkc/pen/jPRWKK?editors=110

BTW, I dont want to go with any javascript based approach.

If anyone, has an alternate for the above with a better apporach, that will be great.

Comment: Better in what sense? Almost any layout will have parent and child elements.

Comment: Is the height dynamic?

Comment: `.panel { display: flex; }`

Comment: Please include all code in your question and refrain from posting external links to it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, yes the height is unknown for both the first as well as the second. But for the outer container ".panel", it is a fixed height.

Comment: @nirmalkc Then make the same fixed height for the previous one also!

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, this is not a Sass problem.  Only post the compiled CSS.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I don't want a fixed height solution. The height of the 1st row `.box-one` is unknown. Based on the height of the 1st row, 2nd row `.box-two` should take the available space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flexbox` can do that.

```css
.panel {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.panel [class*="box"] {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.box-one {
  background: lightblue;
}
.box-two {
  background: lightgreen;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
.tall {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="box-one">
  </div>
  <div class="box-two">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="box-one tall">
  </div>
  <div class="box-two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Paulie, thanks for suggesting flex box.
But I am wondering about the support of it in IE 10?

Because canisue say it is very partial http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Cool, vendor prefix should be fine.

I have tried using your recommendation, but I still came across some issues having the second row going outside the parent container.

Here is my code
http://codepen.io/nirmalkc/pen/NqmNGO?editors=110

Comment: I think I figured out the solution.

Changed `flex: 1 0 auto;` to `flex: 1 auto auto;` and it worked :)

Here is the code http://codepen.io/nirmalkc/pen/MwRybN?editors=110

Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Similarly I will need another solution for a panel inside a panel with such a  situation.

Comment: how about using a flexbox inside a flexbox. Basically I will need a second level flebox and the 2nd flexbox item to take the space that is available.

Here is what I am trying to do.
http://codepen.io/nirmalkc/pen/VLNaWM?editors=110